# How to make a view invisible to touches?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a `ContentView` where I've applied a custom effect to detect taps on it. I also have a transparent `StackPanel` that overlays part of it in order to show some buttons on the bottom left and bottom right.

The problem is that taps on the visible part of the `ContentView` but under the `StackPanel` are not detected (because the taps are actually on the `StackPanel`, which doesn't have the custom effect).

Is there a way to make the `StackPanel` "invisible" to taps or somehow pass the taps through the panel on to the view below it (that is, the `ContentView`)?

Comment: Do you want to bypass touch from stack panel to ContentView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This might be your solution.** **[InputTransparent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.inputtransparent?view=xamarin-forms)** **in XAML ( Xamarin.Forms )**

```
<StackLayout InputTransparent="True"/>
```

This will send the touch effect to the parent view.

Comment: Yes, that worked! I also needed to use `CascadeInputTransparent="False"` to prevent child buttons from being input transparent. Thank you!